# Maven breaks resource stream to jpg once exported to runnable jar

Tags: eclipse, maven, plugins, jar, resources

I've been seen searching high and low for a solution to my problem with maven (which I'm inexperienced with) including various plugins and resource declarations, all unsuccessful. I'm using JavaFX in my application and loading this image works great in eclipse but breaks once exported to a runnable jar. I'm assuming this has something to do with the way maven packages the jar.

```
     public void initialize(){
         Image image = new Image(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("pcoordinatesImage.jpg"));
         diagramImage.setImage(image);
     }
```

I get a NullPointerException: "input must not be null" when executing the jar on command line

I've swapped out more plugins than a glade air freshener in my pom.xml file. I posted the whole pom.xml so you guys can see how little I know and maybe spot some obvious errors

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>EllipsoidCalculation</groupId>
<artifactId>EllipsoidCalculation</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.11</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.10.19</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
      <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
      <version>1.3</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
<resources>
  <resource>
      <filtering>false</filtering>
      <directory>src/main</directory>
      <includes>
          <include>**/*.properties</include>
      </includes>
  </resource>
</resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
                 <configuration>
                    <archive>
                         <manifestFile>src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
                         <manifest>
                           <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                             <mainClass>ellipsoidCalc.EllipsoidCalcMain</mainClass>
                         </manifest>
                    </archive>
                 </configuration>
       </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.3</version>
      <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

The resources are right next to the source code where I want them when I export to a jar so I have no idea why is doesn't work

Thanks for any help!

Heres the contents of my runnable jar file:
[command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoXIy.png)

Comment: First it is not a good idea to filter everything in `src/main` you should think about using only `src/main/resources` furthermore check the case of your images..The runnable jar contains files which do not belong there like junit etc. (You should set things like mockito, junit to `<scope>test</scope>`).

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I've added the scopes to my test dependencies. Can you briefly explain filtering? and the meaning of true vs false for filtering?

Comment: also adding <scope>test<scope> to my test dependencies did not remove them from the jar file when I re-exported

Answer (score 0):

I regret to admit that I found the bug. The "p" in "pcoordinatesImage.jpg" should be capitalized as shown in the screen shot of the command line. That fixed the problem. Oddly enough it didn't break the code in eclipse tho. So anyone else suffering from the same problem, check caps. The pom.xml that was posted appears to be functional, hope it helps